# How to check connection to database via YAML configuration file in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, database

Connect to any database in nodejs whoch is derived from env.

```
mysql:
   host: 
   port: 5432
   dbname: db1
   user: username
   password: 1234
sqlserver:
   host: 
   port: 5432
   dbname: db1
   user: username
   password: 1234
```

this file can be database.yml

in env we have variable set to

ENV.DATABASE = sqlserver or    ENV.DATABASE = mysql

depending on the Database from env connection to that particular database should be made

How this can be achived as INterface driven???